# How can I get ActiveRecord model instances from a raw sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In Rails, I sometimes want to do a query with MySQL that is too complicated for ActiveRecord methods alone.  So I will usually do the following to get back an array of hashes:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ..."

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query.to_a
```

Often times I can get away with just this, but sometimes I still want an array of instances for my model so I can use them for CRUD.

In that case, I've tried this:

```
result.map{|u| User.new(u)}
```

This works fine until I try to do a create, save, or update.  When that happens, I get an error telling me that a record with the same ID already exists.

Somehow, ActiveRecord already knows how to do this with the queries it is able to construct.  How can I do the same thing and make it so that I can transform a complex raw query into a collection of model instances that will alter the table instead of trying to insert and failing?

Answer (score 10):

Use [find_by_sql](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql) e.g.

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM user...")
```

the trouble with doing `result.map{|u| User.new(u)}` is that this creates new `User` objects with the attributes taken from the hashes returned by `exec_query` but these are treated as new, unsaved Active Record models so clash with the existing records if you then try to persist them.

That said, the Active Record query interface is pretty flexible so it could be worth posting some examples of the queries you need to see if these can be modelled without resorting to raw SQL.

Comment: Wow, I forgot that method even existed.  I like this answer, though the only problem I can see is that using aggregate functions or nested queries to create extra attributes doesn't seem to work.  Using the method I came up with, I can add an attr_accessor to my user model so that something like post_count can be returned as an attribute.  But most of the time I won't be needing to do that if I am doing inserts, so it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: For some other cases, [Shadwell's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/120518/shadwell) suggestion to run a query to find the IDs and then a separate `Model.find` can be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

You could either find the objects by calling the [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql) from the class:

```
User.find_by_sql('select users.* from users ... ')
```

Or, alternatively you'd have to [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) the users from the the ids you identify from the query:

```
query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE..."

user_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query.to_a

User.find(user_ids)
```